# Strange text in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to develop an application using vue.js2. I am getting some strange texts in source code. You can see those texts in below image.

[image]

Could anyone say why it is coming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using `scoped` attribute on styles tag in your `.vue` files to scope your styling to the component only.

Any  styles scoped to a component using the `<styles scoped> ... </styles>` , the styles will be applied only to the elements in that component only.

So  [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/) which parses the `.vue` files uses [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/) behind the scenes to achieve this by add adding those weird and unique data attributes.

See [Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) for more info